# I am using subprocess module in python. how do I call python file with arguments using popen with using shell =true

Tags: python, subprocess

```
os.system("python abc.py {file} {option}")
```

I need to convert this to subprocess module without using shell and also need to pass arguments like `{file}` and `{option}`

I have tried it with subprocess module but cant be able to find any solution

Comment: It would be simpler to just import the file and execute the content;

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show your attempted solution; see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: can you show me example of that @Itération122442

Comment: Edit the content of abc.py file into a function, then import the module `import abc` and then execute the function `abc.myfunction(option)`

Comment: Please edit your question to include debugging information (i.e., what you tried). See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Stack Overflow FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Each argument should be a separate value in the list you pass to `subprocess.run()`.

```
subprocess.run(['python', 'abc.py', file, option])
```

Comment: can we use this thing with popen also??

Comment: Yes, all the subprocess code uses the same way of calling.